# How to force sumif() to use string matching (instead of numerical matching)?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, sumifs

How can I force Google Sheets sumif() formula to use string matching? I'm using a **string** criteria on **string** data and it is undesirably using numerical matching.

Example data:

```
1.1     1
1.1     2
1.10    4
1.11    5
```

Doing sumif on the above data yields the value 7, instead of 3 as the "1.10" row is being matched:

```
SUMIF(A1:A,"1.1",B1:B)
```

I can achieve the desired result using query()

```
query(A1:B, "select sum(B) where A matches '1.1' label sum(B) ''")
```

but in my complex real-world use-case I do not find it as intuitive and would prefer to use sumif() if possible.

Online example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s41B3pIWixkiAh7DFvGmcJzrr6gjmQlcO3yYrvuFYzc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Use `"'1.1"`

```
=SUMIF(A1:A,"'1.1",B1:B)
```

to force text match.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a non-numerical character to both the range array and the search:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(A1:A&"x","1.1x",B1:B))`

Answer (score 0):

You may try `filter` function, I also feel surprise `sumif` that will confuse over `1.1 vs 1.10`"

```
=sum(FILTER(B:B,A:A=E7))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `TO_TEXT` function is useful here:

`=arrayformula(sumif(to_text(A1:A),"1.1",B1:B))`

[image]

It needs to be put in `arrayformula` to add up matching values in the columns.